# Curl preg_match

Tags: php, curl

We are downloading images to our computers when we open new webpages. For example: If a webpage has an image(image.jpg), our computer downloads it while we are surfing that page.

Some webpages are using ajax methods. For example: You don't see an image on the page's source codes, however your computer downloads an image. Because, if you click a link on that page, ajax will be showing that image...

Let me show an example:

```
<div id="ajax_will_load_image_here"></div>
```

Okay, how can php curl see (or download) that image? Curl can't see that image when I try to use preg_match function. Actually there is an image. I want to download that image by using php curl. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question correctly there is no convinient way of doing that.

Your crawler/spider would have to parse the website and evaluate javascript.

There are libraries for that but support is very limited.

There are however methods where an actual browser is used to evaulate the page (without displaying it but setting proper environment variables like resolution etc).

Then the generated source including javascript dom modifications is available.

This is for example how the google search previews are generated.

But if you require user interaction it gets pretty specific and complicated.

I am sorry to dissapoint you, but using curl and preg metch the old school way we used to when javascript was not yet so common wont work.

However for most legit use cases this is more than sufficient and websites are today more and more designed to be non-javascript compliant. Especially the content for crawling purposes. It is a must in search engine optimization, and which website doesnt want that?